# Low data transfer rate between Ubuntu laptop and local NAS

Tags: networking, ubuntu, nas

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 18.04, a Zyxel NBG6515 router and Zyxel NAS326 NAS device in local.

I bought a gigabit swtich to connect the router via ethernet cable to improve the data transfer rate (I'm a bit far from router to connect it via ethernet). When I transfer files between my Ubuntu laptop and NAS device using Nautilus, the data transfer rate is approx. 10 MB/s, but I expected much higher transfer rates (50 MB/s maybe?), so I'm a bit dissapointed.

This is may be a bare question, sorry for that, but I'm very junior with this networking stuff. Is this rate expected? Or am I doing something wrong? I thought this may be because the hard drive inside the NAS is poor quality; but it's a *[WDC WD40EFRX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EHBERSE)*, which is reasonably good I think.

I can give more info about the setup if needed. Thanks a lot.

**Edit 1:**

- Laptop ethernet adapter: *Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller*
- Ethernet cables are CAT5e
- Couldn't find exact ethernet adapter for NAS326 but it says *"One Gigabit Ethernet RJ-45 connector"* in hardware specifications in its official specifications page.

Comment: Try `ethtool <adapter_name> | grep -i speed` to determine your actual connection speed. The status LEDs on your ethernet port may also tell you what speed it is using (but there is no standard, refer to the docs of the machines).

Comment: "*I'm a bit far from router to connect it via ethernet*". So it's not too clear how you connect. What do you gain with the switch?